# I want to bind a a non-const lvalue reference to type T to a temporary of type T

Tags: c++, rvalue, temporary, const-correctness

Is there a trick/cast letting me do that?

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getBar(){
  std::vector<int> bar (5,200);   // five ints with a value of 200    
  return bar;
}

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> foo (3,100);   // three ints with a value of 100

  foo.swap(getBar());

  return 0;
}
```

In this specific case

```
foo = getBar();
```

is a good answer. I wonder if there is a way to accomplish that task for  functions other than `swap` taking a non const reference.

Comment: Related: what about `getBar().swap(foo)`?

Comment: It will be a lot easier to approach your question if you had a function other than swap in mind. Is there a concrete problematic scenario we can address?

Comment: Just do `foo = getBar();`.  It'll do the right thing

Comment: This seems to be what rvalue references are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a auxiliary function, the "opposite" of `std::move`

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::remove_reference_t<T> &stay(T &&t) { // perhaps "temporary" is a better name
    return t;
}
```

In your case, the prvalue will materialize into an xvalue that binds to an rvalue reference, which lets us construct an lvalue referring to the same object.

```
foo.swap(stay(getBar());
```

As usual, the temporary lives until the end of the full-expression (to the semicolon), so this is safe (assuming `swap` doesn't try to save the reference somewhere).